# Replacing/removing excess white space between columns in a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

I am trying to parse a file with similar contents:

```
I am a string         12831928  
I am another string           41327318   
A set of strings      39842938  
Another string           3242342
```

I want the out file to be tab delimited:

```
I am a string\t12831928  
I am another string\t41327318   
A set of strings\t39842938  
Another string\t3242342
```

I have tried the following:

```
sed 's/\s+/\t/g' filename > outfile
```

I have also tried `cut`, and awk.

Comment: Are you trying to replace the spaces before the last column (a number) with a tab?

Comment: Are there really spaces after the last column?

Comment: Benjamin W. thanks for the response. Ed Morton just posted a response. I am new to posting and responding on here. I appreciate you taking the time to respond to my question. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use awk:

```
$ awk -F'  +' -v OFS='\t' '{sub(/ +$/,""); $1=$1}1' file
I am a string   12831928
I am another string     41327318
A set of strings        39842938
Another string  3242342
```

Breakdown:

```
-F'  +'           # tell awk that input fields (FS) are separated by 2 or more blanks
-v OFS='\t'       # tell awk that output fields are separated by tabs
'{sub(/ +$/,"");  # remove all trailing blank spaces from the current record (line)
$1=$1}            # recompile the current record (line) replacing FSs by OFSs
1'                # idiomatic: any true condition invokes the default action of "print"
```

I highly recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!  Do you think you could tell me what awk is doing here? break down the command?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E 's/[ ][ ]+/\\t/g' filename > outfile
```

NOTE:  the `[ ]` is `openBracket` `Space` `closeBracket`

`-E` for extended regular expression support.

The double brackets `[ ][ ]+` is to only substitute tabs for more than 1 consecutive space.

Tested on MacOS and Ubuntu versions of sed.

Comment: To format lines of code, indent by `4-spaces`, for inline code, surround the code in *backticks* `'\`'`.

Comment: A blank character isn't a regexp metacharacter so `[<blank>]` is exactly equivalent to just `<blank>` so you can change `[<blank>][<blank>]+` to just `<blank><blank>+`. Also the OP is trying to get tab-separated output, not `"\t"`-separated, so don't escape that.

Comment: Yes, there are several ways to write the regex.  I didn't thing "  +" was obvious to anyone reading it that that was TWO spaces followed by plus sign.  Whereas [ ][ ]+ is a little more obvious.

Comment: Also, the escaped tab char \\t IS needed with the -E extended regex option.  Otherwise you do not get tabs in output.

Comment: @ChuckB that must be something sed-version-specific as it's not the case with GNU sed. To be honest I can't imagine why that'd make sense for any sed but if you say so....

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty comes in the varying number of words per-line. While you can handle this with `awk`, a simple script reading each word in a line into an array and then `tab`-delimiting the last word in each line will work as well:

```
#!/bin/bash

fn="${1:-/dev/stdin}"

while read -r line || test -n "$line"; do
    arr=( $(echo "$line") )
    nword=${#arr[@]}
    for ((i = 0; i < nword - 1; i++)); do
        test "$i" -eq '0' && word="${arr[i]}" || word=" ${arr[i]}"
        printf "%s" "$word"
    done
    printf "\t%s\n" "${arr[i]}"
done < "$fn"
```

**Example Use/Output**

(using your input file)

```
$ bash rfmttab.sh < dat/tabfile.txt
I am a string   12831928
I am another string     41327318
A set of strings        39842938
Another string  3242342
```

Each number is `tab-delimited` from the rest of the string. Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your input has spaces at the end of each line, which makes things a little more difficult than without. This sed command would replace the spaces before that last column with a tab:

```
$ sed 's/[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]*\)$/\t\1/' infile | cat -A
I am a string^I12831928  $
I am another string^I41327318   $
A set of strings^I39842938  $
Another string^I3242342  $
```

This matches – anchored at the end of the line – blanks, non-blanks and again blanks, zero or more of each. The last column and the optional blanks after it are captured.

The blanks before the last column are then replaced by a single tab, and the rest stays the same – see output piped to `cat -A` to show explicit line endings and `^I` for tab characters.

If there are *no* blanks at the end of each line, this simplifies to

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]]*\)$/\t\1/' infile
```

Notice that some seds, notably BSD sed as found in MacOS, can't use `\t` for tab in a substitution. In that case, you have to use either `'$'\t''` or `'"$(printf '\t')"'` instead.

Comment: Thanks again Benjamin W. I will try this out as well.

Answer (score 0):

another approach, with `gnu` `sed` and `rev`

```
$ rev file | sed -r 's/ +/\t/1' | rev
```

Comment: Hi there karakfa, thank you for responding as well.  Ed Morton suggestion worked. I will try your approach in a few and try to respond back.

Answer (score 0):

You have trailing spaces on each line. So you can do two `sed` expressions in one go like so:

```
$ sed -E -e 's/ +$//' -e $'s/  +/\t/' /tmp/file  
I am a string   12831928
I am another string 41327318
A set of strings    39842938
Another string  3242342
```

Note the `$'s/  +/\t/'`: This tells bash to replace `\t` with an actual tab character prior to invoking `sed`.

To show that these deletions and `\t` insertions are in the right place you can do:

```
$ sed -E -e 's/ +$/X/' -e $'s/  +/Y/' /tmp/file  
I am a stringY12831928X
I am another stringY41327318X
A set of stringsY39842938X
Another stringY3242342X
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and **without invisible semantic characters** in the code:

```
    perl -lpe 's/\s+$//; s/\s\s+/\t/' filename
```

Explanation:

```
    Options:
      -l: remove LF during processing (in this case)
      -p: loop over records (like awk) and print
      -e: code follows

    Code:
      remove trailing whitespace
      change two or more whitespace to tab
```

Tested on OP data. The trailing spaces are removed for consistency.